# Xdebug only writes to /tmp

Tags: linux, php, centos, xdebug

I've installed Xdebug on Centos 6.2. It writes `cachgrind` files to /tmp just fine, But I want it to write to /tmp/xdebug instead.

I've added this to my php.ini:

```
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp/xdebug
```

and changed the owner of the folder to `apache:apache` and `chmode` it to 777.

But, it is not writing any files. When I configure it back to:

```
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp
```

It does write files. How can it be fixed ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall from my other reading correctly, the folder on CentOS for xdebug output needs to be owned by the "nobody" account, not apache.